# Cannot ping any machine on local network (embedded linux device)

Tags: linux, networking, ping, arp

I have an embedded linux installation (custom built using buildroot, uClibc and busybox) and I am unable to ping any machine on my local network. My `/etc/network/interfaces` file is as follows

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static 
    address 172.18.255.212
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.18.255.1
```

These values were given to me by our network administrator. The `route` command yields the following output

```
Destination      Gateway     Genmask        Flags   Metric Ref  Use Iface
default        172.18.255.1  0.0.0.0        UG       0      0    0   eth1
172.18.255.0     *           255.255.255.0  U        0      0    0   eth1
```

so it appears that the routing is set up as it should be. Unfortunately, I am completely unable to ping any other machine on this local network 172.18.255.0 - not even the gateway. When utilising connection to another company network that does not have a gateway, I can communicate with all machines on that network, but when the gateway is involved I get nothing.

I have used the Wireshark utility on another machine to sniff all packets and I can see that my embedded device IS transmitting ARP requests whenever I try using that device to ping the 172.18.255.1 gateway so I know that the ethernet adaptor is working. Unfortunately, the request is either not getting through to the gateway or is being ignored. I am at a loss here - I am not a network specialist at all. Is there anything I have failed to do in order to get my machine to be recognised by the network? What kind of thing leads to ARP requests being ignored or failing to reach the gateway? Any help/advice will be gratefully received.

Comment: You contact the network administrator and ask what's going on.

Comment: is the same subnet mask configured on the other machines and the gateway?

Comment: Can you give us the output of "arp" and "ifconfig"?